# Разрешите спор, как правильно?

Tags: падежи

Есть предложение.
Необходимо предоставить доступ в квартиры специалист**У** (**ам**).
Или же правильно "Специалист**А**" (**ов**).
Моя версия - первый вариант. Или я ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 1):

Доступ в квартиру специалист**а**(**ов**) дает возможность войти в квартиру где живет специалист(ы). А если самому специалисту(ам) нужно попасть в квартиру, то требуется дательный падеж.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: Необходимо предоставить (что?) доступ в квартиры (кому?) специалистам.

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

1) У глагола "предоставить" сильное управление: кого-что кому.  Следовательно,  «предоставить  доступ специалистам».

2) ДОСТУП  1.Место, по которому приблизиться к чему-л. В ущелье нет доступа. 2. Впуск, допуск куда-л. или к чему: Получить д. на завод, в архив.  Получить д. к секретным документам. 3.Проникновение чего-л., куда-л., во что-л. Д. кислорода в лёгкие.

Следовательно,  «допуск в квартиры».

3) Вариант с Р.п.  (. Д. кислорода в лёгкие) НЕ ПОДХОДИТ, так как относится к неод. существительным и имеет значение «проникновение».